# Update an array of array of objects in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of arrays of objects defined something like this.

```
const childSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number
})

const parentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    items: Number,
    transactions: [[childSchema]]
})

const Transaction = mongoose.model('Transaction', parentSchema)
```

So, this schema will result in the data something like this.

```
{
    name: "Car"
    items: 16
    transactions: [
        [
            {
                name: "Ford",
                price: 120
            },
            {
                name: "Fiat",
                price: 100
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                name: "Toyota",
                price: 150
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

So, how should I query the data in the transactions? How should I find, update and push into the specific transactions array. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating and pushing are quite trivial with mongoose:

```
const transaction = await Transaction.findOne({}).exec()

// you can now modify it (almost) like a javascript object

// push transaction
transaction.transactions.push([{ name: "Toyota", price: 150 }])
// or
transaction.transactions[0].push({name: "Toyota", price: 150})

// update
transaction.transactions[0][0].name = "Name"

// don't forget to save changes
await transaction.save()


// find transaction with 'Ford'
Transaction.findOne({'transactions[0].name': 'Ford'})
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I was busy finding a way to update it with a proper MongoDB solution. But anyway, this works and it's all that matters.